# Failed to call function, _fbBatchedBridge is undefined[react-native][linux][android]

Tags: react-native

I have a problem, while running a react native application on an android device, my application works perfectly but when i debug it remotely, it shows this error.

I have a second terminal running with react-native start(also tried with npm start) a new chrome tab also gets open in my browser but it shows that error is related to debuggerWorker.js.

I cant understand whats happening, any help will be highly appreciated!!!

```
Environment: OS: Linux 4.15 Node: 10.0.0 Yarn: Not Found npm: 6.0.0 Watchman: 4.7.0Xcode: N/A Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4819257 Packages: (wanted => installed) react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1 react-native: 0.55.4 =>
```